# Differentiate request from Windows 8 app

Tags: php, zend-framework, windows-8, windows-store-apps, user-agent

I have a multi platform system, serving different devices.
I have Android client, IOS client, a website, XBOX... and a Win8 app.

What I need to do is differentiate the requests made by the Win8 app in the server side.

I was trying by through the User Agent, but that doesn't work, it's the same User Agent for the Win8 app and an IE installed in the same terminal(PC).
Any idea?

My backend is Zend Framework 2 (PHP)

PS: I can't modify the headers in the request of the Win8 app, it's a third party app, the code is a black box :(